# How to create a php getter and setter in a javascript way

Tags: javascript, php

Please is it possible to create getters and setters in a JavaScript way in php. For example:

**JavaScript**

```
function test(){
 var clr = "";
 Object.defineProperty(this, "color", {
  set:function(val){
   val=="red"?clr=val:val="others";
  },
  get:function(){
   return clr;
  }
 });
}
```

*Now setting*

```
var testObj = new test();
testObj.color = "red";
```

*And getting*

```
var testObj = new test();
var color = testObj.color;
```

*Instead of this in php*

```
$testObj = new test(); 
$testObj->setColor("color"); //Setter
$testObj->setColor(); //Getter
```

*But this in php*

```
$testObj = new test(); 
$testObj->setColor = "red";//Setter
$testObj->setColor;//Getter
```

Which the value would be proccessed before being assigned. Also i would like to know the name for the JavaScript way creating getters and setters. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't used PHP in a while, so forgive me if the syntax is slightly off, but you can use the [`__set`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) and [`__get`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) [magic methods](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php):

```
private $props = [];

public function __set($property, $value) {
    switch($property) {
        case 'color':
            $this->props['color'] = $value == 'red' ? $value : 'others';
        break;
    }
}
public function __get($property) {
    switch($property) {
        case 'color':
            return $this->props['color'];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it's what i wanted